# Maven: how to edit resource files?

Tags: sql, maven-2, maven-3

I have a mavenized SQL project, which has a few SQL scripts. These scripts are basically Oracle statements of the form:

```
insert xyz into some_table;
show errors
```

These files are to be copied to a deploy project, but for the statements to work, some modifications have to be made.

For the moment, we are editing files manually (with the help of Notepad++) so that they turn out like this:

```
insert xyz into some_table\
```

Is there any way to do this with Maven? I'm not sure this is exactly resource filtering, and I'm pretty sure that this is not the purpose of Maven. I've been looking at the [Maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) for the moment, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a fairly simple text replacement, then you can use maven-replacer-plugin:

http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/

If all else fails, you can also use maven-antrun-plugin to do anything that ant can do.  Here is a prior question that discusses this:

[Full search and replace of strings in source files when copying resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196394/maven-full-search-and-replace-of-strings-in-source-files-when-copying-resources)