# Android preprocessor macros with 2 targets

Tags: android, eclipse, preprocessor

I hope someone can help me with this one.

I'm have been developing for the iPhone for a long time, and I'm used to set a preprocessor macro so I can use `#ifdef` in code to do different things with different targets.

How do I do something like that with Android? As far as I know Java does not support preprocessor macros. How can I have a different behavior with different run configurations in Eclipse?

Comment: Had a similar question before, this post answered it for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813853/ifdef-ifndef-in-java

Comment: Thank you! I have a server with two different urls for testing and produktion. Ended up making a static final boolean test and doing something like this: public static final serverUrl = test ? testUrl.com : produktionUrl.com;