# How does System.getProperty("fast") work?

Tags: java, android, debugging, conditional-compilation

In my search for a #ifdef-equivalent in Java, I found this great thread that describes a way to do conditional compilation: [#ifdef #ifndef in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813853/ifdef-ifndef-in-java/1813873#1813873)

What I don't understand is how this really works:

1. Why is the 2nd form
   (System.getProperty) better than the
   1st one (false/true)?
2. "fast" is not one of Java's
   [predefined properties](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/Javasystemproperties.htm). This
   probably means that I have to define
   it in my code somewhere. What is the
   best place to do this in an Android
   app? Is onCreate() a good place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The first one will be optimized by the compiler. That is, you'll set the boolean property to 'true' and the compiler will discard the else-branch of conditionals. If you set it to false, the then-branch will be discarded. You have to recompile your code if you want to switch fast to slow or vice versa.

2) You'll have to define the system property when you launch your app. Setting VM-wide properties is a previleged operation. I'm not an android expert but I doubt that you can set these in the onCreate-event of an android app. The core idea behind System.getProperty is, that you'll be able to switch the application mode when you start the virtual machine by passing an additional command line argument like -Dfast=true.

Comment: Thank you! 1++ Do I understand correctly from your answer that the 2nd form (which uses System.getProperty) is **not** optimized by the compiler?

Comment: Yes, System.getProperty() is a method invocation. The compiler cannot predict the result of this invocation and will thereby not remove one of the branches statically.

Answer (score 1):

1. The 2nd is more flexible, since you could decide to switch something on or off while starting. The 1st example will be optimized away, so you need to recompile to change the value.
2. A Systemproperty is set by -Dproperty=value (Note: before command line arguments which are passed to the main method)

Comment: Thank you too for this great clarification. I already accepted the answer by @Sebastian so please accept my +1 as a token of my appreciation.