# What's the equivalent of C++'s "#ifdef #endif" macro in JSP?

Tags: jsp, jspinclude, page-directives

What's the equivalent of C++'s `#ifdef` `#endif` macro in JSP?
Is there such thing in JSP?

I want to conditionally include files in one JSP or another.
Reason for doing that is because I have a nested setup (nested jquery ui tabs). I prefer to include files in the outermost layer for the "release" version.  But for the "debug" version, I prefer to include file in the inner layers so I can debug individual pages. 
I'm using `<%@ include ... %>` to include files.

If it's possible, how would you implement that?
I think JSP include action (`<jsp:include>`) would work, but that's probably slower than JSP include directives.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813853/ifdef-ifndef-in-java) thread. And probably [this](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/i18n/tlddoc/i18n/ifdef.html) can shed some light as well.

Comment: Due to deprecation, the Apache link is now _approximately_ [this](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jakarta/taglibs/deprecated/i18n/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/taglibs/i18n/IfdefTag.java) (that's the source, but if you can't read that…)