# Platform specific code in Eclipse

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

We're developing a java desktop/Eclipse RCP application with a graph-layout component. We faced issues with the GUI scaling on newer(8, 8.1, 10) versions on windows, it appeared that one can only retrieve the scaling factor through win32 api calls, so we added a little DLL that does this and call it through JNI. Works fine on windows, works fine in maven on linux/osx since the class is never instantiated there.

The problem is that to get the scaling factor, we need the window handle, which we retrieve like this:

```
public float getScale(GC gc) {
  return getScale(gc.getGCData().hwnd);
}
```

where `GC` is an `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC` and the following call is to the dll. However, that lines gives me a compilation error when debugging on linux, since that object doesn't have a `hwnd` variable. How do I solve this in a cleaner way without compilation errors?

Comment: Is this an Eclipse RCP application (which has mechanisms for this) or just an SWT app?

Comment: Added clarification, it's an eclipse rcp application. What mechanicsms? I looked around a bit but couldn't find any.

Comment: You can use a 'plugin fragment' with a platform filter so that it is only used on the selected platform.

Comment: This might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813853/ifdef-ifndef-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a plug-in fragment, as [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) sugested. A fragment can have a [platform filter](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbundle_manifest.html) which prevents it from being loaded when the current platform does not match the filter expression.

A platform filter for Windws 32bit would look like this:

```
Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.ws=win32) (osgi.os=win32) (osgi.arch=x86))
```

A fragment must also specify a host bundle. At runtime, the fragments resources are *merged* into the class space of the host bundle

```
Fragment-Host: the.parent.bundle
```

To avoid compilation errors, you would have an interface or abstract class in your host bundle and two fragments with different implementations for Windows and Linux.

The Windows implementation could safely access the `hwnd` field and the Linux implementation could return a value indicating that scaling is not available/fixed.

For example, the host bundle would have a `ScaleProvider`:

```java
class abstract ScaleProvider {

  ScaleProvider getInstance() {
    String className = ScaleProvider.class.getName() + "Impl";
    try {
      Class<?> implClass = ScaleProvider.class.getClassLoader().loadClass( className );
      return ( ScaleProvider )implClass.newInstance();
    } catch( ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e ) {
      throw new RuntimeException( e );
    }
  }

  abstract float getScale( Gc gc );
}
```

For brevity, the *implementation loader* and the *interface description* are in one type. The `getInstance()` code expects a class named `ScaleProviderImpl` to be present in the same package.

The `ScaleProviderImpl` class is provided by the fragment that matches the current platform and would have a class

```
class ScaleProviderImpl extends ScaleProvider {
  float getScale( Gc gc ) {
    // platform-specific implementation
  }
}
```

This example assumes that there is always a matching platform specific fragment present. But you could of course change the `getInstance()` code to return a default implementation if no `ScaleProviderImpl` can be found.

Comment: getName() is missed, should be String className = ScaleProvider.class.getName () + "Impl"; . Worked for me after this fix.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I‘ve edited the answer accordingly. The new